# Как отсортировать таблицу по значению агрегатной функции?

Tags: laravel

Есть 2 таблицы рестораны и отзывы:

```
restaurants: - id, name, ...
review: id, id_restaurant, rating.
```

Как можно реализовать запрос, чтобы отсортировать рестораны по среднему рейтингу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$restaurants = DB::table('restaurants')
        ->join('restaurant_reviews', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('restaurants.id', '=', 'restaurant_reviews.id_restaurant')
            ->orderByRaw('avg(rating)');
        })
        ->get();
```